# SDL - Mouse input

Tags: c++, sdl

I've read through the documentation regarding mouse events, and I have worked through tutorials regarding mouse input handling too. Though, this problem still exists:

I have a camera and an opengl context and I simply want the camera to rotate IF the mouse moves and the left mouse is clicked. So, naturally I wrote this code:

```
void processEvents()
{
    float deltaX = 0;
    float deltaY = 0;

    while (SDL_PollEvent(&pEvent) != 0)
    {
        if (pEvent.type == SDL_QUIT)
            pApp_isRunning = false;

        if (pEvent.type == SDL_MOUSEMOTION && pEvent.button.button == SDL_BUTTON_LEFT)
        {
            deltaX += pEvent.motion.x;
            deltaY += pEvent.motion.y;
            pCamera.rotate(deltaX / REFRESH_RATE, deltaY / REFRESH_RATE);

            cout << "Mouse = (" << deltaX << ", " << deltaY << ")" << endl;
        }

        if (pEvent.type == SDL_MOUSEMOTION && pEvent.button.button == SDL_BUTTON_RIGHT)
        {
            deltaX += pEvent.motion.x;
            deltaY += pEvent.motion.y;
            pCamera.rotate(deltaX / REFRESH_RATE, deltaY / REFRESH_RATE);

            cout << "Mouse = (" << deltaX << ", " << deltaY << ")" << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

The left mouse seems to be responding to the event since it updates the motion coordinates. But, if I were to use the exact same code but just with SDL_BUTTON_RIGHT, nothing happens! It's as though SDL needs another way of understanding the right mouse button. I've worked with GLFW, SFML, GLUT, Qt, and for SDL to not have consistency in grepping right mouse button events is dazzling imo. What am I doing wrong here? Is there a correct way of handling mouse input in the way I've described? As in:

If the left mouse button is clicked and the mouse has moved: rotate camera.
If the right mouse button is clicked and the mouse has moved: rotate camera. I must be missing something here, or maybe it's a bug with SDL2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace:

```
        if (pEvent.type == SDL_MOUSEMOTION && pEvent.button.button == SDL_BUTTON_RIGHT)
        {
            deltaX += pEvent.motion.x;
            deltaY += pEvent.motion.y;
            pCamera.rotate(deltaX / REFRESH_RATE, deltaY / REFRESH_RATE);

            cout << "Mouse = (" << deltaX << ", " << deltaY << ")" << endl;
        }
```

by:

```
        if (pEvent.type == SDL_MOUSEMOTION && pEvent.button.button == SDL_BUTTON(SDL_BUTTON_RIGHT))
        {
            deltaX += pEvent.motion.x;
            deltaY += pEvent.motion.y;
            pCamera.rotate(deltaX / REFRESH_RATE, deltaY / REFRESH_RATE);

            cout << "Mouse = (" << deltaX << ", " << deltaY << ")" << endl;
        }
```

I remember having that kind of "bug" back to the day I was playing with SDL (also, check the SFML if you want a c++ wrapper of the SDL)

Comment: Thanks, that appears to have resolved my problem. Do you also know about mouse scrolling on SDL too? I've used if (pEvent.type == SDL_MOUSEWHEEL) and simply added pEvent.wheel.y to deltaY. Although deltaY (and deltaX) get initialised to (0, 1) if going up, or (0, -1) contrary. Is that expected?

Comment: Glad it helped, remember to mark my answer as accepted!
For the wheel I recommend to create an other question. But yes I think it is the expected behavior as the X will be use when scrolling from right to left. (some mouse allow that move)

Comment: This is not proper use of the SDL_BUTTON macro...  and if it works then it is only hiding the real issue.

Answer (score 5):

There's a common mistake here.  SDL_Event is a union, so you should not be using the event.button field if you have checked that the type is SDL_MOUSEMOTION.  In other words, you are invoking undefined behavior and it is not a problem with SDL and the right mouse button.

Instead, use the motion.state field:

```
if(pEvent.type == SDL_MOUSEMOTION && pEvent.motion.state & SDL_BUTTON_LMASK)
    ...
```